# How to search in a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, search

I have a array which looks like this:

```
array(500) {
[1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "Final Fantasy VII"
    ["price"]=>
    string(5) "11.69"
    ["shop"]=>
    string(4) "9507"
    ["url"]=>
    string(77) "https://de.gamespl...."
  }
[2]=> ...
```

and I want to check if a specified game is still remaining in this array based on price, shop, url and name. My problem now is, how can I search through the array?

Because I do not have the ID of the game, it is much more difficult because the array gets stacked up like `[1] => array (4) ... [2] => ...`.
Is there maybe a better way to stack up the array? - Does it has any advantage to store the product without the ID? - Does it accelerate the search?

Because my focus is speed/optimization and I need the fastest way to complete this search... Because I have to check 5000 games I need the fastest way.

Does anyone has an idea or can tell me which one is the fastest way and how I can search in this array?

Comment: The fastest way is to store all this information in a database and then use SQL to search it for you.

Comment: But if I search for the games more than 25000 times isn't it much slower than a local array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this first of all getting all columns required and then search as complete array in the your data.

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/772941)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$array=array(
    array(
        "name"=> "x",
        "price"=> "12000",
        "shop"=> "212121",
        "url"=> "http://www.someurl.com",
    ),
    array(
        "name"=> "xy",
        "price"=> "11000",
        "shop"=> "1212121",
        "url"=> "http://www.someotherurl.com",
    )
);
// date need to search for 
$gameName="xy";
$gamePrice="11000";
$gameURL="http://www.someotherurl.com";
$gameId="1212121";

//Creating array from data for searching.
$dataToSearch=array(
    "name"=> "xy",
    "price"=> "11000",
    "url"=> "http://www.someotherurl.com",
    "shop"=> "1212121",
);
if(in_array($dataToSearch, $array))
{
    echo "Game found!";
}
```

Comment: Two question. You do not have the ID and you do not are checking the price, shop and url... Only if all 4 attributes are matching the game is still existing!

Comment: Does it work also in my array or do I have to remove the ID which is pointing to an array?

Comment: @FrazeJr. yes it will work in your array as well, and which ID you are taking about?

Comment: Thank you! - The question is now, if it is faster to loop through the array then executing 25000 SQL queries...

Comment: Yes it will be surely faster than making no. of queries, because here you complete data is in your  process memory.

Comment: And is there maybe a better way then looping through an array? - A faster way?

Comment: This is the fastest way, because here you are not looping by yourself and applying checks for all fields of array

Comment: Might be that PHP function `in_array( . . .)` looping in it self. but is more better than searching by your self.

Comment: Ah, I know what you mean. But look what I found http://nickology.com/2012/07/03/php-faster-array-lookup-than-using-in_array/ - I just googled `How does in_array work?`

Comment: Thats strange but its documentation does not say anything like that http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php, now we can say it is easy way but you can do it with looping as well. Further Read and Development can be more helpful in this case

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Anyway, Thank You! - But maybe you know a faster way than this. What I now want to do is to check if the game from my website is still in the table. So I'm comparing two arrays - Is there a faster way to do that then looping through the array an check it with you method?

Comment: An another way can be like this for specific search field, lets say you want to query that array with `name` as `Final Fantasy VII`, you can do one thing like `json_encode(your complete array)` then searching this `"Final Fantasy VII"` this term with double quotes in the `json` string using `strstr`. this can be an option i am not saying that its is more efficient then this.

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal approach, in this case, would be to use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) hash lookup instead of [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). As the primer has `O(1)` (in general) and former `O(n)`. This means that with [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) searching time will depend on the length of the array. You can read more about [Big-O Complexity](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

To use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) we have to apply [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to the array. In our case, we use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to create keys.

```
function encodeGame($game)
{
    return json_encode([
        $game["name"],
        $game["price"],
        $game["shop"],
        $game["url"],
    ]);
}

$games = array_combine(array_map('encodeGame', $games), $games);

var_dump(isset($games[encodeGame($game1)]));
var_dump(isset($games[encodeGame($game2)]));
```

Here is the [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/607f5aa5fdd8dc65d8708d61bb1aa84a06dfdc44).